# Flutter - how do I rotate an object on a CustomPainter canvas?

Tags: flutter

How do you rotate an object drawn on a canvas in Flutter (not the whole canvas, just the object)?

The following does not work. Error is: *This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.*

```
    Transform.rotate(
        angle: pi,
        child: canvas.drawPath(
            getTrianglePath(Offset(secondhandX, secondhandY)),
            secondhandBrush));
```

Here is the full code:

```
// imports omitted

class TimerDialPainter extends CustomPainter {

  Path getTrianglePath(Offset position) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(position.dx - 20, position.dy - 20)
      ..lineTo(position.dx + 40, position.dy + 40)
      ..lineTo(position.dx - 20, position.dy + 40)
      ..lineTo(position.dx - 20, position.dy - 20);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    int centerX = size.width / 2;
    int centerY = size.height / 2;
    int secondsArc = 60;

    Paint countBrush = Paint()
      ..color = (Colors.red) 
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 3;

    var secondhandX = centerX + 80 * cos(secondsArc * pi / 180);
    var secondhandY = centerY + 80 * sin(secondsArc * pi / 180);

    Transform.rotate(
        angle: pi/3,
        child: canvas.drawPath(
            getTrianglePath(Offset(secondhandX, secondhandY)),
            countBrush));

    } //I feel this is not a right place to solve this?? 
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try rotating the canvas and paint it. Then rotate it back to previous value

```
 @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double centerX = size.width / 2;
    double centerY = size.height / 2;
    int secondsArc = 60;

    Paint countBrush = Paint()
      ..color = (Colors.red)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 3;

    num secondhandX = centerX + 80 * cos(secondsArc * pi / 180);
    num secondhandY = centerY + 80 * sin(secondsArc * pi / 180);
    canvas.rotate(40);
    canvas.drawPath(
        getTrianglePath(Offset(secondhandX.toDouble(), secondhandY.toDouble())),
        countBrush);
    canvas.rotate(0);
  }
```

Comment: Good thinking, that might work, but it will create very complicated math. Is there another way?

Comment: In path you can also add a transform and use a matrix4 to rotate or scale in any axis. https://medium.com/flutter-community/advanced-flutter-matrix4-and-perspective-transformations-a79404a0d828

Comment: Doesn't rotate just use that under the hood? In other words, how will it work differently to use it directly?

Comment: I haven't tried transforming a path before but according to what I read and understood we should be able to rotate a path (getTrianglePath in our case) using the transform method and add rotation also and then draw it on canvas. Since it's already rotated it should paint a rotated path

Comment: @Kaushik_Chandru I did the whole thing "manually" (with a matrix rotation), and that worked, obviously.

Comment: Awesome would be happy to see some codes and output if you can share it here as an answer